# Can we have a better reputation graph on profile summary page?

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, reputation-graph

I often visit my profile to make quick investigation of my account, and sometimes i see there Loss in Reputation like,

 <sub>[image: Reputation loss]</sub>

loss but i only get that information from tabs, **Reputation graph** doesn't show me how much reputation I've lost, It only shows Reputation Gain.
[image: Reputation Graph]

---

I believe most of users only go for Quick Analysis by Reputation graph of their Profile page.
It will be good, If the Reputation  graph of profile summary shows not only Gain in Reputation but also the loss in Reputation. 


**Proposed Design** for Reputation Graph on profile summary page:

[image: Proposed Design]

Comment: But, it does. The bars only indicate daily totals.

Comment: It shows the **total reputation** earned per day. How exactly you want to show changes? This request really makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is this graph instead? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/222250/stargazer?tab=reputation&sort=graph

Comment: But sometimes we lose some reputation, It will be better if we see this on our graph too.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you lose reputation but what happens when you gain more in a single day than you lose? How should that be represented on your graph?

Answer (score 4):

The reputation graph shows ***net***, daily, gain **or loss**.  Consider [this user's graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2273202/deepak?tab=reputation&sort=graph):

[image: Normal rep graph]

See how the net rep losses are shown in red?

---

Or perhaps you want each bar to show gain and loss something like this? :

[<sub>(Click for larger image)</sub>

[image: Possible new rep graph?]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPTD2.gif)